# Overlapping of Box2d bodies, and get stuck

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I'm using box2D with cocos2D in my iOS game. While creating box2d bodies randomly on the screen(as they are too much in number) some time two bodies are created so closely that they got stuck with each other. The following bodies (image) are created using polygon.

[image]

So how can i detect these bodies and separate them from each other? so i can move the body individually currently they behave like a single body.

Comment: if there's enough surrounding free space Box2D will automatically force the two bodies apart. Enable debug drawing to verify your polys are setup correctly (counterclockwise!).

Comment: @LearnCocos2D there is enough space. and polys are created using Physics editor

Comment: weird, and no joints are autogenerated? The same shot with debug drawing enabled would help clear things up. I could also imagine that box2d may be having troubles separating the bodies when there are lots of fixtures/shapes. These shapes I expect to use 10+ shapes.